# PC configuration to download and build android AOSP source code

Tags: android, android-source

I would like to know if my PC configuration is enough to download and build Android AOSP source code? The [AOSP docs](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) say:

> If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you need at least 16GB of RAM/swap and 30GB or more of disk space in order to build the Android tree.

**My PC configuaration :**

```
Intel Core 2 Duo processor
2 GB RAM
250 GB HDD
```

Now I plan to install both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 as dual boot. Is my configuration is enough or will I need anything else?

Comment: I'd say you are light about 14GB of RAM.  Making up the short fall with a large swap partition might work, but expect it to take a long time because all that swapping.  If you are doing this 'just because' then fire it up and see how it goes.  If this is for more serious work I suggest you start saving for upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

The question was posted in 2013 and it appears that Android AOSP has gotten much larger over the years. You definitely need more up to date and faster hardware than a Core 2 Duo Processor with 2GB of RAM and a 250 GB hard disk these days.

The build requirements currently (November 2020) say you need 250GB of free space just to download the source. Then you need another 150GB of free space to do a build.  https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements

You also need a 64 bit Linux environment for the build itself.

From my limited experience there are several places or choke points that should be considered for any modern build environment and Android AOSP is big.

- processor speed and number of cores and threads
- amount of RAM and RAM type/speed
- amount of disk space and type of disk hardware

I am working with Android AOSP with a PC with the following setup:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Intel i3-9100F (4 core CPU, 3.60GHz with 6MB cache)
- 32 GB of RAM, 2666MHz DDR4 on a micro ATX motherboard
- 1TB NVMe drive
- NVIDIA RTX2070 GPU (graphics card is for TensorFlow machine learning)

I've been considering upgrading the CPU to an Intel i7-9700F (8 core CPU) as it appears the Android build will spread the amount of work between the cores and a build would take fewer hours. On the other hand, this is not my primary work PC so it probably isn't necessary.

When I start a build using `m -j4` after doing a `make clobber` it takes right at 4 hours to do the build with the current Android AOSP source and this hardware. The PC is doing nothing other than the build and the exhaust 120mm case fan speeds up until the build completes.

Answer (score 0):

What is written in the AOSP documentation is true. You need a 16GB ram in order to build AOSP. If you have less RAM than that then you might face java heap memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to my previous experience with building AOSP 12, I tried many configurations but the following was the minimum viable requirements:

- CPU Intel core i7 11th generation
- RAM 16 GB DDR5
- Storage SSD at least 500 GB for building multiple versions of AOSP. I think 400 is adequate for building a single target.

The estimated source code size for AOSP 13 (full) is about 150 GB. After building, based on the selected target(s), this needs to be expanded to 400 GB.

You may face a few errors originated from ninja, but you can handle it with proper swap configuration and using threading options in your build.

This was my story with minimum requirements. It is obvious that using more capacity of hardwares gives you speed and saves your time.